# Will call to fmap be removed when newtype is a Functor?

Tags: haskell

If I create a newtype:

```
newtype Bloo a = Bloo a
```

And make it a Functor

```
instance Functor Bloo where
    fmap f (Bloo a) = Bloo $ f a
```

Will

```
fmap f (Bloo a)
```

be converted to

```
f a
```

in the compiled program?

Comment: Seems likely. I can't imagine what would be left after type erasure. Written more explicitly, I could see `fmap @Bloo f` evaluating to `f`, and `Bloo a` becoming `a`, making it impossible *not* become `f a`.

Comment: For this specific case, consider `fmap = coerce`. With that definition, even if fancy optimizations don't fire (e.g. because some `Functor`-polymorphic thing is not inlined), you're still guaranteed that `fmap f (Bloo a)` reduces to `f a` in one evaluation step -- indeed, `fmap f` reduces to `f` in one step, whether supplied with a next argument or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost certainly, yes, but it does require `fmap` to be inlined, which may not happen under certain circumstances. For example if it is deemed to large (not really relevant in this case) or if you annotate it with a `{-# NOINLINE fmap #-}` annotation. In those cases it will just be a function that applies `f` to its argument, like: `fmap f x = f x`.

You can try it out for yourself. Take this code for example:

```hs
-- Test.hs
newtype Test a = Test a
  deriving Show

instance Functor Test where
  fmap f (Test x) = Test (f x)

main = print $ fmap (+ 1) (Test 1)
```

And compile it with `ghc Test.hs -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -fforce-recomp`. That will output a bunch of stuff, but somewhere you will find the `main` function:

```hs
-- RHS size: {terms: 8, types: 9, coercions: 3, joins: 0/0}
main
  = $ (print ($fShowTest $fShowInteger))
      ((+ $fNumInteger 1 1) `cast` <Co:3>)
```

If you squint a bit, you might see that the `fmap` is gone and it is simply summing `1` and `1`.

If you enable optimizations with `-O1` then it will even evaluate that `1 + 1` at compile time:

```hs
-- RHS size: {terms: 1, types: 0, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
main3 = 2

-- RHS size: {terms: 9, types: 11, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
main2
  = case $w$cshowsPrec4 11# main3 [] of { (# ww3_a2vc, ww4_a2vd #) ->
    : ww3_a2vc ww4_a2vd
    }

-- RHS size: {terms: 3, types: 1, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
main1 = ++ $fShowTest2 main2

-- RHS size: {terms: 4, types: 0, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
main = hPutStr' stdout main1 True
```

This output is a bit more obscure, but I hope you can recognize `main3 = 2` which is the result of `1 + 1`.

If you add a `{-# NOINLINE fmap #-}` pragma (and disable optimizations again) you will get:

```hs
-- RHS size: {terms: 13, types: 13, coercions: 3, joins: 0/1}
main
  = $ (print ($fShowTest $fShowInteger))
      ($cfmap1_r1CZ
         (let { ds_d1Cs = 1 } in
          \ ds1_d1Cr -> + $fNumInteger ds1_d1Cr ds_d1Cs)
         (1 `cast` <Co:3>))
```

Which is also complicated, but you might recognize `$cfmap1_r1CZ` which is a name-mangled version of the `fmap` function.